# How can I calculate the physical sensor size of the smartphone camera from EXIF data and know the depth of each pixel?

Tags: python, image-processing, distance, pixel, exif

I saw this post below and used an A4 paper to calculate the size of the image sensor in the received image.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo

Using the information in the EXIF ​​file, I was able to obtain the focal length, and by knowing the height and width of the paper in the image with the formula mentioned in the post, as well as knowing the distance to the A4 paper mounted on the wall, I obtained the image sensor size. But the calculations were not correct and the size of the calculated image sensor is wrong. This code I wrote is to calculate the length and width of the image sensor

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from exif import Image
import math

input_list = []
coordinate_list = {}
max_number_click = 3
image_path = 'otagh_j_2.jpg'


def click_event(event, x, y, arg1, arg2):

    # checking for left mouse clicks
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        # displaying the coordinates
        # on the Shell
        if len(input_list) <= max_number_click:
            print('counter number', len(input_list))
            print(x, ' ', y)
            input_list.append(np.array([x, y]))
        else:
            print('4 points were calculated before')

    # checking for right mouse clicks
    if event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        # displaying the coordinates
        # on the Shell
        if len(input_list) <= max_number_click:
            print('counter number', len(input_list))
            print(x, ' ', y)
            input_list.append(np.array([x, y]))

        else:
            print('4 points were calculated before')


def sort_points(unsorted_list):

    # Separation of x coordinates from y coordinates
    x_coordinates = unsorted_list[:, 0]
    y_coordinates = unsorted_list[:, 1]

    # Find the minimum and maximum values in the coordinates
    min_coordinates = np.amin(unsorted_list, axis=0)
    max_coordinates = np.amax(unsorted_list, axis=0)

    # Sort points based on their location in the selected object
    width_points = {'L': unsorted_list[np.where(x_coordinates == min_coordinates[0])[0][0]],
                    'R': unsorted_list[np.where(x_coordinates == max_coordinates[0])[0][0]]}
    height_points = {'D': unsorted_list[np.where(y_coordinates == max_coordinates[1])[0][0]],
                     'U': unsorted_list[np.where(y_coordinates == min_coordinates[1])[0][0]]}
    # width_points = [unsorted_list[np.where(x_coordinates == min_coordinates[0])[0][0]],
    #                 unsorted_list[np.where(x_coordinates == max_coordinates[0])[0][0]]]
    # height_points = [unsorted_list[np.where(y_coordinates == max_coordinates[1])[0][0]],
    #                  unsorted_list[np.where(y_coordinates == min_coordinates[1])[0][0]]]

    return width_points, height_points


def calculate_distance_pixel(point_1, point_2):
    return math.sqrt(((int(point_1[0])-int(point_2[0]))**2)+((int(point_1[1])-int(point_2[1]))**2))


def find_sensor_size(distance, real_dimension_of_object, width_points, height_points):

    # Read the exif information of the received photo
    with open(image_path, "rb") as input_file:
        image_exif = Image(input_file)

    # Read focal length and the length and width of the received photo
    focal_length = image_exif['focal_length']

    width_of_image = image_exif['pixel_x_dimension']
    height_of_image = image_exif['pixel_y_dimension']

    # calculate the real focal length
    focal_length = distance / (distance / focal_length + 1)

    # Obtain object dimensions in pixels
    object_height_pix = calculate_distance_pixel(height_points['D'], height_points['U'])
    object_width_pix = calculate_distance_pixel(width_points['L'], width_points['R'])

    # Calculate the dimensions of the image sensor
    sensor_size_height = (focal_length * height_of_image * real_dimension_of_object[1]) / (distance * object_height_pix)
    sensor_size_width = (focal_length * width_of_image * real_dimension_of_object[0]) / (distance * object_width_pix)

    if sensor_size_height > sensor_size_width :
        temp = sensor_size_height
        sensor_size_height = sensor_size_width
        sensor_size_width = temp

    return np.array([sensor_size_width, sensor_size_height])




# driver function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # reading the image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # displaying the image
    cv2.imshow('image', img)

    # setting mouse handler for the image
    # and calling the click_event() function
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)

    # wait for a key to be pressed to exit
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    width_p, height_p = sort_points(np.array(input_list))
    sensor_size = find_sensor_size(distance=2900, real_dimension_of_object=[210, 300], width_points=width_p,
                                   height_points=height_p)


    print('use points for calculation')

    # close the window
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And these are examples of the images I sent to the code. The distance sent in the code with the number 2900 mm is the distance of the paper image stuck to the back of the chair.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18_dTlUDirJaksrJj_UfEhCf6yd6WwNj-/view?usp=sharing

and

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ui99gpU2i0JFumLivLpoEyHn3QTcfD8a/view?usp=sharing

I have illustrated these four points as input

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiAPwbNI2EJPTnUZ4cYk1cPrUw8YexJq/view?usp=sharing

This is the output of the above code for the photo 'otagh_j_1.jpg'

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xyt2z0WKYLwqMvBL4RrU6KRv3VfmBHNw/view?usp=sharing

My first question is, does the camera have to be vertical when shooting? Or is the phone slightly misaligned causing an error?

Is there a better way to get the length and width of the image sensor?

My ultimate goal is to be able to get the actual length between the two desired points, such as the length or width of the carpet in the image.

Comment: How _does the camera angle of the phone matter when shooting?_ is a programming question? If the formula is correct and result is wrong, maybe your code has problem. Post your code ([mre]), sample input, expected output and actual one you get.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I provided more information needed to explain the question.